# Get a list of all the prefixes of a string

Tags: ruby

is there any inbuilt function in the Ruby `String` class that can give me all the prefixes of a string in Ruby. Something like:

```
"ruby".all_prefixes => ["ruby", "rub", "ru", "r"]
```

Currently I have made a custom function for this:

```
def all_prefixes search_string
  dup_string = search_string.dup
  return_list = []
  while(dup_string.length != 0)
    return_list << dup_string.dup
    dup_string.chop!
  end 
 return_list 
end
```

But I am looking for something more rubylike, less code and something magical.
Note: of course it goes without saying `original_string` should remain as it is.

Comment: I think what you have is enough good enough, since that looks very rarely used thing.

Comment: This is maybe a long shot, but if you want to find distinct abbreviations for a set of strings, you can use `Abbrev`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html

Comment: @nTraum: Can you change that comment into an answer please? /me is itching to give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'

string = 'ruby'

compare do   

  toro2k do
    string.size.times.collect { |i| string[0..i] }
  end

  marek_lipka do
    (0...(string.length)).map{ |i| string[0..i] }
  end

  jorg_w_mittag do
    string.chars.inject([[], '']) { |(res, memo), c| 
      [res << memo += c, memo] 
    }.first
  end

  jorg_w_mittag_2 do
    acc = ''
    string.chars.map {|c| acc += c }
  end

  stefan do
    Array.new(string.size) { |i| string[0..i] }
  end

end
```

And the winner is:

```
Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
jorg_w_mittag_2 is faster than stefan by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
stefan is faster than marek_lipka by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
marek_lipka is faster than jorg_w_mittag by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
jorg_w_mittag is similar to toro2k
```

Comment: I'll deny it! Benchmarks for something as trivial as this should not be much of a factor in determining which solution is best, unless you're pushing limits in terms of input length, etc. The real-world differences won't matter as much as readability. Coincidentally I have found @toro2k's other answer to be my preference.

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no built-in method for this. You could do it like this:

```
def all_prefixes(string)
  string.size.times.collect { |i| string[0..i] }
end
all_prefixes('ruby')
# => ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
def all_prefixes(str)
  acc = ''
  str.chars.map {|c| acc += c }
end
```

Comment: fastest of all the solutions presented here.

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
str = "ruby"
prefixes = Array.new(str.size) { |i| str[0..i] }  #=> ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]
```

Comment: this is actually the cleanest of all(imho).

Answer (score 4):

This is maybe a long shot, but if you want to find distinct abbreviations for a set of strings, you can use the [`Abbrev`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html) module:

```
require 'abbrev'

Abbrev.abbrev(['ruby']).keys
=> ["rub", "ru", "r", "ruby"]
```

Comment: this would have been the best answer if i could do `Abbrev.abbrev('ruby').keys`  instead of `Abbrev.abbrev(['ruby']).keys`, but this ofcourse is pretty cool

Answer (score 3):

A little bit shorter form:

```
def all_prefixes(search_string)
  (0...(search_string.length)).map{ |i| search_string[0..i] }
end
all_prefixes 'ruby'
# => ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]
```

Comment: thanks, although your answer is same as toro2k , but that one looks slightly more cleaner.

Comment: Actually your code returns `["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby", "ruby"]`, you should use an exclusive range, i.e. `0...string.size` instead of `0..string.size`. And `string[..]` should be `search_string[...]`.

Comment: @sahildhankhar I agree, although I will leave my answer to show alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_prefixes(str)
  str.chars.inject([[], '']) {|(res, memo), c| [res << memo += c, memo] }.first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "ruby"    
prefixes = str.size.times.map { |i| str[0..i] }  #=> ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two not mentioned before and faster than those in the @toro2k's accepted comparison [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078489/1672429).

```
(1..s.size).map { |i| s[0, i] }
=> ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]

Array.new(s.size) { |i| s[0, i+1] }
=> ["r", "ru", "rub", "ruby"]
```

Strangely, nobody used `String#[start, length]` before, only the slower `String#[range]`.
And I think at least my first solution is quite straightforward.

Benchmark results (using Ruby 2.4.2):

```
                           user     system      total        real
toro2k                14.594000   0.000000  14.594000 ( 14.724630)
marek_lipka           12.485000   0.000000  12.485000 ( 12.635404)
jorg_w_mittag         16.968000   0.000000  16.968000 ( 17.080315)
jorg_w_mittag_2       11.828000   0.000000  11.828000 ( 11.935078)
stefan                10.766000   0.000000  10.766000 ( 10.831517)
stefanpochmann         9.734000   0.000000   9.734000 (  9.765227)
stefanpochmann 2       8.219000   0.000000   8.219000 (  8.240854)
```

My benchmark code:

```
require 'benchmark'

string = 'ruby'
@n = 10**7

Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
  @x = x
  def report(name, &block)
    @x.report(name) {
      @n.times(&block)
    }
  end
  report('toro2k') {
    string.size.times.collect { |i| string[0..i] }
  }
  report('marek_lipka') {
    (0...(string.length)).map{ |i| string[0..i] }
  }
  report('jorg_w_mittag') {
    string.chars.inject([[], '']) { |(res, memo), c| 
      [res << memo += c, memo] 
    }.first
  }
  report('jorg_w_mittag_2') {
    acc = ''
    string.chars.map {|c| acc += c }
  }
  report('stefan') {
    Array.new(string.size) { |i| string[0..i] }
  }
  report('stefanpochmann') {
    (1..string.size).map { |i| string[0, i] }
  }
  report('stefanpochmann 2') {
    Array.new(string.size) { |i| string[0, i+1] }
  }
end
```